# Ansible to call execute a shell script with a specific tag

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to execute shell script from ansible playbook and also trying to capture the output on the console.

When I run the playbook I always get the below error "  "out.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!""

How do I run the script and get the output on the console?

```
---
- name: Deploy book
  hosts: All_Servers
  become_user: test_user
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Print a message
      command: sh ../scripts/test.sh
      register: out
    - debug: var=out.stdout_lines
      tags:
      - tag1
```

```
cat ../scripts/test.sh
echo "Test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question

> ... execute shell script from `ansible-playbook` and also trying to capture the output on the console ...

you need to have [all tasks tagged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html) which you like to run if using  `ansible-playbook --tags="<tags>"`.

> ... it may be useful to run only specific parts of it instead of running the entire playbook.

```
---
- name: Deploy book
  hosts: all
  become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
  become: true
  
  tasks:

    - name: Run script
      shell:
        cmd: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/scripts/test.sh"
        warn: false
      changed_when: false
      register: result
      tags: test,run,script

    - name: Show result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
      when: not ansible_check_mode
      tags: test,show,result
```

If only the task `Show result` is tagged or run but not `Run script`, Ansible will try to show only the result which isn't there. Therefore the error message `.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"`.

You can test it by running the above test with different tags to get different behavior.

By using a [`block`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) with a tag, you have [just tagged both tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-blocks).

> If you want to apply a tag to many, but not all, of the tasks in your play, use a block and define the tags at that level.

Regarding executing a shell script you may have a look into [whats the difference between Ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/) or [difference between `shell` and `command` in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663332/).