# Cd command is not working in ansible when using in -a tag

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I am using the below command and i am getting an error **[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'cd'**

**ansible servers -a "cd /etc/ansible"**

I know that we can make use of playbooks but I just don't want to create, is there any possibility of executing the above command? please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do by running `cd`?

Comment: `/etc/ansible` does not generally exist unless Ansible is installed on the system, which is not the case for managed hosts.

Comment: @Jack I finally got it I was trying to change the directory on the system and yes /etc/ansible was not on the system my bad. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According your question I understand that you like to execute [ad-hoc commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html) on remote Managed Nodes, using an inventory like

```ini
[servers]
test1.example.com
test2.example.com

[test]
test1.example.com
test2.example.com
```

The Ansible Engine can be [installed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements) on one [Control Node](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/basic_concepts.html#control-node) only to make connections to the remote [Managed Nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/basic_concepts.html#managed-nodes) to manage them. Therefore a command like

```bash
user@ansible.example.com:~$ ansible test --user ${REMOTE_ACCOUNT} --ask-pass -m shell --args 'cd /etc/ansible'
SSH password:
test1.example.com | FAILED | rc=1 >>
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /etc/ansible: No such file or directory non-zero return code
test2.example.com.example.com | FAILED | rc=1 >>
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /etc/ansible: No such file or directory non-zero return code
```

may fail since Ansible usually isn't and [don't need be installed at all on the remote Managed Nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements). You may test your connection and execution in general via

```bash
user@ansible.example.com:~$ ansible test --user ${REMOTE_ACCOUNT} --ask-pass -m shell --args 'cd /tmp'
SSH password:
test1.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>

test2.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
```

Because of your mentioned Error Code 2 (`[Errno 2]`, RC2) you may also have a look into [whats the difference between Ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/) or [difference between `shell` and `command` in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663332/).

Comment: Thanks, I have finally got it right with the below command format
 ansible servers -m command -a "cd /etc && cat os-release". This type of command works but is it the best way?

Comment: You can just run `ansible servers -m command -a "cat /etc/os-release"`